# SwiftUI adding a button to navigationView applies padding to whole view

Tags: swiftui, padding, navigationview

I have a view which looks like this:

[image]

And here is its the code:

```
    struct SettingController: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            MainList()
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}
```

Now I add a code to add a button to navigationView like so:

```
    struct SettingController: View {
    @State var isToggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            MainList()
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                        HStack {
                                            Button("Unlock All") {
                                                isToggle.toggle()
                                            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$isToggle) {
                                                SubscriptionModalView()
                                            }
                                        })
        }
    }
}
```

But the results came out like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of those paddings!?

Comment: did you try `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` modifier

Comment: @Enes Karaosman: No I did not, And this solved my problem! Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```swift
List(..) {
   ListItem {
   ..
   }
   .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
}
```

Try using `PlainListStyle`

Comment: Thank you so much, this is golden!

Comment: I thought I did, sorry!